# How do I add a checkbox (SPBuiltInFieldId.SelectedFlag) to a list view?

Tags: 2010, view

I would like to add a selection checkbox into a View *inside a WebPart*.... a view that presently does not have a checkbox.

I know there is a  [SelectedFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.selectedflag%28v=office.15%29.aspx) field in SharePoint that gives me a GUID... but I have no clue how to use it. Obviously I cannot just go `myview.ViewFields.Add(SPBuiltInFieldId.SelectedFlag)` because GUIDs cannot be directly added.

Is there a proper way to add a checkbox using `SPBuiltInFieldId.SelectedFlag`?

*(I looked through my View and there is a "Selected" field, but it contains, of all things, an arrow icon. It doesn't look, or act, like the checkboxes I've seen in OOTB views, that's for sure.)*

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EMASU1m.png]

Edit: I found [a "great" list](http://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/sharepoint-internal-field-names-sharepoint-2010/) that has a bunch of GUIDs. Tried to duplicate the list. Could not do that at all -- ID doesn't even contain GUIDs... it contains 0x00, 0x01... etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the select checkbox to appear, you can enable it through the UI by enabling the tabular view. If you are doing this through code, you'd want to look at the [SPView.TabularView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spview.tabularview(v=office.14).aspx) property.

Comment: For whatever reason, this appears to have no effect when the view itself is inside of a webpart. It's surrounded by code modifying the number of allowed items, the fields, etc, so it's not an update problem either...